# How to make only 1 img that has been added to the DOM disappear on double-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, double-click, dom-manipulation

So I have built a small DogAPI that some of you are probably familiar with.  I want to make mine sort of like a collage but I want to give people the option of double-clicking on a picture and removing it if they wish.  So far I have created the images with JQuery and appended them to a container.  Adding event listeners makes all the images disappear because they all have the same ID's.  Achieving this is way out of my skill level (Beginner).

https://codepen.io/drxl/pen/VwbQZyK

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <h1>Dog Collage!</h1>
    <p>Select a dog and create your collage!</p>
    <div id="breeds"></div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow" id="imgs">
</div>




   // fetches dog breed list/shows error if applicable
async function start() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
        const data = await response.json()
        breedList(data.message)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("There was a problem fetching the breed list.")
        alert("There was a problem fetching the breed list.")
    }
}


//load breed list in dropdown menu
start()
function breedList(dogList) {
    document.getElementById("breeds").innerHTML = `
    <select onchange="loadByBreed(this.value)">
        <option>Choose a dog breed</option>
        ${Object.keys(dogList).map(function (breed) {
        return `<option>${breed}</option>`
    }).join('')}
    </select>
    `
}

//load images
async function loadByBreed(breed) {
    if (breed != "Choose a dog breed") {
        const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images`)
        const data = await response.json()
        createImgs(data.message)
    }
}

//show randomized images
function createImgs(images) {
    let imageContainer = $(".slideshow");
    let dogImgs = $('<img>');
    dogImgs.attr("src", images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]);
    dogImgs.addClass(".dogPic")
    imageContainer.append(dogImgs);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case if you need image to be removed on double click you can use jQuery double click event.

```
$(document).on('dblclick', ".dogPic", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Yea I figured it out but yes you did address the double click part

Answer (score 1):

```
// with jQuery you could just add a click listener to the class and remove the element, just add this below all your code
$(document).on('click', ".dogPic", function(){
    $(this).remove();
})
```

you need to fix ur typo first though:

```
dogImgs.addClass(".dogPic")
```

becomes

```
dogImgs.addClass("dogPic")
```

Comment: Nice man, that worked!  I though I tried doing that with regular JS but it didn't work, maybe I was only selecting the ID and not the class, well I had the right idea!